# Symfony: extend entity without creating table

Tags: symfony, inheritance, entity

I'm using Symony 3 with Sonata Admin and I already have a CheckAdmin, with its entity, repository and service already configured. The list, show, edit routes... all working right.

My next step is that I want another Admin, Entity and Repository (call it HourControl) that inherits from Check but without creating another table, I want to show the info in a different way in another section of my app.

My HourControlAdmin extens from CheckAdmin and I have the $baseRouteName and $baseRoutePattern configured correctly and I can see the new routes. The HourControlEntity also inherits from CheckEntity with my new methods (I don't have any extra configuration).

In the service I'm doing this:

```
app.admin.hour_control:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\HourControlAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\HourControl, AppBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: 'my_group', on_top: true, label_catalogue: 'my_catalogue', icon: '<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>' }
        public: true
```

but when I go to de the list view I get this error: `No entity manager defined for class AppBundle\Entity\HourControl`

What do I have to configure?

Thank you!

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/advanced_configuration.html#inherited-classes

Comment: After adding that configuration to the service of the parent admin and I get this error: ```Invalid service "app.admin.check": the value of argument "hourControl" of method "Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin::setSubClasses()" must be null, an instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference or an instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition, string given.``` Besides, this looks that only affects to the admin, and that is not the problem, the goal is to inherit HourControlEntity from CheckEntity